# go to anchor after page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would one go about making the full page render and then go to the anchor tag? 
I am doing a link in a mail that will link you to the direct page and then it will need to go down to the specific id. Iam getting the id via Angular, so i need the page to load before it tries to go to the anchor.

```
id="{{idtoanchor}}"
```

what ive tried with angular:

```
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http, $q, $anchorScroll, $location, $timeout)
```

First try:

```
    $timeout(function() {
    var currentURL = (document.URL);
    var result = /[^/]*$/.exec(currentURL)[0];
    $anchorScroll('#'+'result');
  });
```

Second:

```
    $timeout(function() {
    $location.hash('id');
    $anchorScroll();
     });
```

Third as suggested in answer:

```
 this.$onInit = function () {
    var currentURL = (document.URL);
    var result = /[^/]*$/.exec(currentURL)[0];
    location.hash = "#" + result;
      };
```

I cant seem to get any of these to work
Even tho i call the $timeout, it fires before the ng-repeat is done loading.

Answer (score 0):

$timeout is not a reliable solution. In angular DOM is rendered after the required data is fetched (a promise is returned which ensures that angular gets the data from API). So to run some code after the DOM is rendered you need to use the available Lifecycle Hooks in angular. For example:

```
function MyCmpController($element) {
   var clickHandler = function () {
      // do something
   };
   this.$onInit = function () {
      $element.on('click', clickHandler);
      //or whatever your logic is.
   };
}
```

Comment: How would i use this in my situation? when i want to go to the specified anchor tag via the url?

Comment: You can write the code for scroling inside `$onInit` hook.

Comment: does not work, it does not fire the first time the page is loaded via www.url.com/something#id, only fires when the page is reloaded